# Elm websockets with a Rust server

Tags: websocket, rust, elm

I'm wanting to use Elm for my web front end, and Rust for the server.  But, I'm running into an issue where the websockets version from elm-socketio doesn't work with rust-websocket.  As far as I can tell elm-socketio has websockets version "2.0.0" (a string I found searching socketio.js that comes with elm-socketio), while rust-websocket has version "13".  In Rust an exception happens when the mismatched version is received.  I commented out the version check just to see what would happen, and I get this:

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: RequestError("Missing Sec-WebSocket-Key header")', src/libcore/result.rs:731
```

So I guess my question is can these two be made to work with each other without significant work?  Is there really a version 2.0.0 of websockets, and is that different from [RFC6455](https://github.com/miksago/RFC6455/blob/master/protocol.txt) which is what rust-websocket refers to (and has version "13")?

Comment: Are you providing the `Sec-WebSocket-Key` header where appropriate? Additionally, I think those versions are the versions of the *libraries*, not necessarily the version of the websocket protocol.

Comment: you know, I have no idea.  I'm taking the rust demo server and testing it with the elm demo client.  The elm client works when it is run against the node.js server that it comes with for testing.  Re the version, all I know at this point is that the version doesn't match what rust is expecting.  I'll see if I can get it to print out what its receiving though.

Comment: Ok, looks like the version that rust is seeing is 'none'.  huh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems socket.io has it's own protocol (see https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-protocol). 
It's confusing because

> "The socket.io protocol can be delivered over a variety of transports."

Websockets are a possible transport layer for socket.io.
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-protocol#transport

You need to find a rust-socket.io library.

Comment: ok websockets != socket.io.  I guess I was just thinking that's what they named their websockets library.  I don't know that I really need socket.io (seeing as I didn't know what it was haha) so I might go the other direction and find an elm websocket library instead.  I'm not seeing a rust socket.io lib anyway.